# Decorator Pattern Hides Decoratee's Interfaces

Tags: c#, decorator

```
public interface IRender
{
  void Render();
}

public interface IUpdate
{
  void Update(float deltaTime);
}
```

I have classes that implement IRender, some of these also implement IUpdate.
By using the decorator pattern I am able to extend their Render method.

```
public abstract class Decorator: IRender
{
  protected IRender decoratee;

  public Decorator(IRender decoratee)
  {
    this.decoratee = decoratee;
  }

  public virtual Render()
  {
    decoratee.Render();
    // add custom rendering code here.
  }
}
```

The beauty of this is that I can created custom rendering behaviour by wrapping an object into multiple decorators like a babushka doll.

My problem is the fact that the IUpdate interface, as well as any other the decoratee implements, will now be hidden by the decorator. I have a number of Systems that accept a list of objects, and operates on them according to the interface they implement. The decorated class will only expose the IRender interface.

What is the cleanest way to get around this issue?

Comment: Can't you just apply the decorator at the point at which the decoration is needed?  Or if you decorate `Foo` does `DecoratedFoo` **need** to become the new `Foo`?

Comment: There are times where I keep references to both the original object and the decorated one, but in this case it would prove too messy to deal with. I was thinking maybe a factory method would work, though as far as I can tell it means I'd have to create decorators for every possible combination of interfaces.

Comment: How many different interface combinations are we talking (or is this purely a philosophical question)?

Comment: Oh, right now its 3 extra interfaces so that makes an extra 3! = 6 classes per decorator

Comment: Are these two interfaces used on domain objects? Their names are nouns (not verbs), so it sounds like that is the case.

Comment: They are plain old OOP classes. I'm just using the decorator pattern to avoid an explosion of classes.